# Python selenium clicking of adobe flash icons without reference element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.5

I am working with Silienium and I am able to open the website using firefox driver. However, I am now running into a wall as the website is flash based.

Please look at image 1 which shows the homepage for the website. I need the silenium to click on the arrow location but when I right click on the page to extract html or xpath for buttons, it doesn't show anything.

[image]

Comment: one choice is to go with position based operations like going to certain co-ordinates and click here is example https://stackoverflow.com/a/26385456/7887883

Comment: How do you locate the pixels co-ordinates?

Comment: There are chome plugins available like mouse position

Comment: I don't think it is possible to click as the co-ordinate needs reference element and there is no way to find xpath or id of anything on pure adobe flash page. Am I correct?