# Trying to download file throught chrome: Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, headless-browser

I am using Selenium with Python to download certain files from a website.  I am trying to access a option called "View all products >>". From there, you could select the kind of file(csv, xlsx) and then you should download it  easily. My problem is that I cannot access that "View all products" area. I've tried in so many ways. I'll attach my code and a screenshot with the structure of website. I cannot post entire HTML because it is a website restrictive only to it's paid users.

[image].
The five links:

- 1 and 2. (Here "View All Products" appears twice):

  ```
   <a class="yui3-c-reportdashboardwidget-reportLink" href="./embedded.html?showGDLogo=false#project=/gdc/projects/e05jwlnny6rlxyt5ib9r6479279crrq8&amp;dashboard=/gdc/md/e05jwlnny6rlxyt5ib9r6479279crrq8/obj/4817&amp;tab=8473392139f7&amp;s=/gdc/projects/e05jwlnny6rlxyt5ib9r6479279crrq8|analysisPage|head|/gdc/md/e05jwlnny6rlxyt5ib9r6479279crrq8/obj/3630" title="Headline - View All Products Link" target="_self">Headline - View All Products Link</a>
  ```
- 3 and 4. (Here "View All Products" appears twice):

  ```
   <span class="yui3-c-reportdashboardwidget-reportLabel" title="Headline - View All Products Link">Headline - View All Products Link</span>
  ```
- 5:

  ```
   <div class="number" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(0, 61, 76);" id="yui_3_14_1_1_1540109592048_72886">      View all products &gt;&gt;</div>
  ```

The link that I want to handle is number "5", because I think that is the one I need to click(), so that I can download the report afterwards.

My code for this part:

## View All Products Button

```
#product_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='c-oneNumberReport yui3-widget yui3-c-onenumberreport yui3-c-onenumberreport-content yui3-widget-content-expanded drillable']")[-1]
#product_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//div[text()='View all products >>']"))
product_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='ember-view reportInfoPanelHandle point-to-top']")[-3]
product_button.click()
#product_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#####actions = ActionChains(driver)
#actions.move_to_element(product_button).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
###########actions.move_to_element(product_button)
###########actions.click()
#actions.sendKeys(Keys.Return);
#actions.build().perform()
```

Update::::

[image]
[image]

Here is the HTML for "Download As..":

```
<span class="button-text"><script id="metamorph-39-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>Download as...<script id="metamorph-39-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></span>
```

HTML for "CSV ( raw data)":

```
<ul id="ember2849" class="ember-view reportExportMenu gdc-menu-simple" style="position: absolute; top: 106px; left: 15px; z-index: 3005;"><li id="ember2850" class="ember-view reportExportMenuItem">
<a data-ember-action="17"><script id="metamorph-47-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>PDF (Portrait)<script id="metamorph-47-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></a>
</li><li id="ember2851" class="ember-view reportExportMenuItem">
<a data-ember-action="18"><script id="metamorph-48-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>PDF (Landscape)<script id="metamorph-48-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></a>
</li><li id="ember2852" class="ember-view reportExportMenuItem">
<a data-ember-action="19"><script id="metamorph-49-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>XLSX...<script id="metamorph-49-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></a>
</li><li id="ember2853" class="ember-view reportExportMenuItem">
<a data-ember-action="20"><script id="metamorph-50-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>CSV (formatted)<script id="metamorph-50-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></a>
</li><li id="ember2854" class="ember-view reportExportMenuItem">
<a data-ember-action="21"><script id="metamorph-51-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>CSV (raw data)<script id="metamorph-51-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></a>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: Is there one "View all products" link on page only?

Comment: There are five, as I see.The one that I want to access has this structure: " <div class="number" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(0, 61, 76);" id="yui_3_14_1_1_1540109592048_72886">      View all products &gt;&gt;</div>"

Comment: And how about other links? They have the same HTML?

Comment: With exact index. But it's weird. For example when I run one of the xpath :#product_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//div[text()='View all products >>']")) it just says that the element not interactable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code to click required element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

link = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[starts-with(normalize-space(), "View all products")]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", link)
link.click()
```

Comment: It gave me this Exception: "WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1448, 958)"

Comment: Try updated answer. Does it work now? Also share complete exception. DOes it looks like *"..another element receives the click..."*?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!! If I put 2 screenshots of how it looks now can you advise me very shortly how to write the code to press: "Download As..." and afterwards from dropdown "CSV (raw data)"? I'll update the post now.

Comment: Hmm... Try something like `wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[starts-with(., "Download as")]'))).click()` and then `wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[. ="CSV (raw data)"]'))).click()`

Comment: Hello Andersson! Just one more question. If I want to click on that "View all Products >>" and not on that Arrow(pointing downwards) above it, how do I proceed with that?

Comment: Try XPath `//span[.="Download as..."]`

Comment: It gives me : "NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[.='Download as...']"}". But I don't search the "Download As". If you look at the picture from the post, for the moment we click at that circle with a arrow above "View all Products >>". Now I need to click directly on that "View all Products >>" and not on that circle above it.

Comment: @user7362809 , oh, so you mean that when you're trying to click element with XPath `//div[starts-with(normalize-space(), "View all products")]` actually the round arrow button intercepts the click?

Comment: Yes sir @Andersson! That's what is happening for the moment. Don't really know why...

Comment: @user7362809 , you can try either [click with offset approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807258/selenium-click-at-certain-position) which is preferable way or using JavaScript to make that arrow button just disappear. You can also open new ticket regarding this new issue

Comment: I will try firstly with offset approach! Thank you! If it doesn't work I'll open a new ticket.

Comment: Hello again @Andersson! I've observed one thing. On my laptop(which has a 14' inch display) selenium clicks on that round arrow button. But if I move the output windows of chrome on the other monitor(24' inch) it clicks just right on the "View all Products >>" button. I've tried with offset approach but can't get it right. This is what I've wrote: "action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(link, 40, 30)
    action.click()
    action.perform()"  Basically, the round arrow is 25 x 25 pixels

Comment: @user7362809 , `40`, `30` is too much. Try just few (`1` - `3`) pixels down

Comment: I've tried with 1,2,3 but it doesn't work :( It doesn't click anywhere I think...

Comment: @user7362809 , try to set window size explicitly `driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)` to force same behavior on desktop and laptop, but I'm not sure that it will work...