# how to use selenium to click an element in canvas

Tags: python, selenium, canvas

button in canvas:
[image]

Inspector of element
[image]

Because the button is in the canvas, and not the HTML, how do I tell python selenium webdriver to click the button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python selenium click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button)

Comment: @smith what you have tried?

Comment: If that button has static location, try to select canvas and click by button coordinates

Comment: @Andersson  can you give the sample code, I wanna finish this tutorial automatically.

Comment: Check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807258/selenium-click-at-certain-position)

Comment: @Andersson  I have used move_by_offset with a coornate , but there's no error and no reaction

Comment: @Andersson  Do u use skype , I will describe these phenomenon to you

Comment: This might mean that you're clicking on wrong location. Try to change coordinates a little and check behavior. No I have no skype

Comment: @Andersson i tried so many times and change the coordinates , And I use page ruler , It still doesn't work ,