# Python Selenium, click at a specified x y position

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

So, I have looked at some very old questions but none of them answer my question, i want to click an absolute x y position but no DOMs no XPATHs nothing. Just x and y positions that need to be clicked.
Thank you in advanced!

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807258/selenium-click-at-certain-position) and a lot more, but that linked above is the closest to what I want.

Comment: what error message did you get or where are you stuck ?

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Selenium [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/). 
You can click anywhere within the viewport using **ActionBuilder**

In the following code,

- A sample webpage will open in Chrome
- The page will be displayed for **5 seconds**.
- The mouse pointer will **move to location (64,60)** which happens to be a link on the page.
- The mouse will **click** at that location, thus clicking on the link.

#### Note:

You will not see your mouse icon move to the location on the screen, however, the mouse pointer does actually move to that position.

#### Code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.action_builder import ActionBuilder


# Open Webpage
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://selenium.dev/selenium/web/mouse_interaction.html')

# Sleep for 5 seconds before clicking on the link at position (64,60)
sleep(5) 

# Move to position (64,60) and click() at that position (Note: you will not see your mouse move)
action = ActionBuilder(driver)
action.pointer_action.move_to_location(64, 60)
action.pointer_action.click()
action.perform()
```